# Efficiently Detecting Kangaroo Words

Tags: python, string

This is a bit of a puzzler, and I wanted to get an ideal algorithm for this type of question. The problem is focused on kangaroo words, which are words that have all the same letters in order as the main word. It's easiest to provide an example. If we take the word (which seems to be floating about online for this type of question) - courage.

courage

***co***u***r***ag***e*** -> ***core***

***co***ura***g***e -> ***cog***

Here is working code to detect the lines above:

```py
def areAllCharsInWordInOrder(word, lookup_word):
    is_kangaroo_word = True
    curr_idx = 0
    are_all_letters_consecutive = True
    for individual_char in lookup_word:
        try:
            new_idx = word.index(individual_char, curr_idx)
            if new_idx - curr_idx == 1:
                are_all_letters_consecutive = are_all_letters_consecutive and True
            else:
                are_all_letters_consecutive = False
            curr_idx = new_idx
        except:
            return False

    if are_all_letters_consecutive:
        return False
    return True
```

However, the caveat for the question comes with the fact that the letters may not be consecutive. So if we look at `devil` and `evil`, these are not kangaroo words because evil is all in order of `devil`. However, `devilishly` and `evil` would be because: d***evi***lish***l***y would match ***evil***.

The nuance comes in that now - I believe - we have to explore every possible matching index to see if it's a valid path. Is this true? Is there a more optimal algorithm? This was my cleanest attempt (lightly tested).

```py
def findAllIndexes(char, curr_idx, word):
    return [i for i, ltr in enumerate(word) if ltr == char and i > curr_idx]

def kangarooHelper(lookup_word, lookup_idx, curr_idx, are_all_letters_consecutive, word):
    if lookup_idx >= len(lookup_word):
        # we're done we've iterated through the whole word
        if not are_all_letters_consecutive:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    new_indices = findAllIndexes(lookup_word[lookup_idx], curr_idx, word)
    if len(new_indices) == 0:
        return False

    return any(kangarooHelper(lookup_word, lookup_idx+1, new_idx, (new_idx - curr_idx == 1) and are_all_letters_consecutive, word) for new_idx in new_indices)

def areAllCharsInWordInOrderFixed(word, lookup_word):
    # Should return false if they're in order
    is_kangaroo_word, are_all_letters_consecutive = True, True
    lookup_idx = 0
    if len(lookup_word) == 0:
        return True
    try:
        curr_idx = word.index(lookup_word[lookup_idx], 0)
    except:
        return False
    return kangarooHelper(lookup_word, lookup_idx + 1, curr_idx, are_all_letters_consecutive, word)
```

Again, it's been lightly tested, but I'd love to clean up both algo and code.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(areAllCharsInWordInOrderFixed('encourage', 'urge')) # True
    print(areAllCharsInWordInOrderFixed('devil', 'evil')) # False
    print(areAllCharsInWordInOrderFixed('devilishly', 'evil')) # True
    print(areAllCharsInWordInOrderFixed('encourage', 'nrage')) # True
    print(areAllCharsInWordInOrderFixed('encourage', 'rage')) # False
```

Thanks! Any advice and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a regex-based approach to the problem. We form a regex from `lookup_word` by adding `.*` between each letter in the word. Then we attempt to match the regex against `word`. Since `.*` is inherently greedy, you will get the longest possible match inside word. You can then compare the length of the matched string to the length of `lookup_word`, and if the matched string is longer, then `lookup_word` is a kangaroo word:

```py
import re

def areAllCharsInWordInOrderFixed(word, lookup_word):
    regex = '.*'.join(lookup_word)
    match = re.search(regex, word)
    return match is not None and len(match.group()) > len(lookup_word)

print(areAllCharsInWordInOrderFixed('encourage', 'urge')) # True
print(areAllCharsInWordInOrderFixed('devil', 'evil')) # False
print(areAllCharsInWordInOrderFixed('devilishly', 'evil')) # True
print(areAllCharsInWordInOrderFixed('encourage', 'nrage')) # True
print(areAllCharsInWordInOrderFixed('encourage', 'rage')) # False
```

Output:

```
True
False
True
True
False
```

Alternatively you can take an iterative approach. There are two conditions that need to be true for the input to be a kangaroo word:

- the letters of the lookup word must be present in the word in order
- there must be at least one extra letter between the letters of the lookup word

The first condition can be tested by checking each letter in turn to see that there is an occurrence of it after the previous letter in the word. The last condition can be checked by testing that the first occurrence of the first letter is more than the length of the word away from the last occurrence of the last letter. For example:

```py
def areAllCharsInWordInOrderFixed(word, lookup_word):
    first = start = word.find(lookup_word[0])
    if first == -1:
        return False
    for c in lookup_word[1:-1]:
        start = word.find(c, start+1)
        if start == -1:
            return False
    end = word.rfind(lookup_word[-1], start+1)
    # don't need to check for end == -1 as the next test will fail if it is
    return end - first >= len(lookup_word)
```

The results are the same as the regex version.

Comment: Thing of beauty! Regex definitely seems like the way to go. Good stuff.

Comment: @jlarks32 yeah, the regex solution is nice and elegant. I've added an iterative solution as well just out of interest.

Comment: Ah doh keeping track of first and start is a lot easier than doing the recursive approach ugh. Nice job yeah that totally checks out. Super clean code as well thanks again